# Adding .jar files to React native

Tags: jar, react-native

I am trying to make an native module for React Native. The Native module I am going to build is based on [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/). When I am  adding the Sinch libary one needs to some .jar files and select "Add as library" in Android Studio. When I try to add my project to Android Studio and add Sinch I get this error: `requiring unknown module "ReactPerf". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install"`

and the emulator looks like this: [eumlator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRl1D.png)
Do anyone have any experience on adding .jar files to their project either through Android Studio or something else? Or do someone know how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In "YouProjectName/android/app/build.gradle" file, there is one line code:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
```

It means you can add you "*.jar" files into "YouProjectName/android/app/libs" folder. Good luck.