# How to include '.jar' files in the React-native for Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, frontend

My English is poor.

I'm a FRONT-END developer.

Now we need an App can use Bluetooth Printer, coding with React-Native for Android.

The Printer's manufacturer provided a SDK file,extension is 'jar'.

Please tell me how to use this SDK in the React-Native? then how to import in the JSX files?

Comment: Can you share the details about the library which you want to use in react native?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding `*.jar` to the Project is done by using `build.gradle` file:

- If you want to add a `jar` file to the project, Facebook had already done on your behalf! 
  **Just add a `libs` folder into the `android/app` directory of the project with your `jar` file** and enjoy!

[image]

- If you want to add a `jar` file to a `native-module` then add the line of `compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])` into the `dependencies` part of `build.gradle` file of the native-module.

**Example-1:**

After I added *okhttp-3.4.1.jar* file into the lib folder, I also add that package name to the dependencies part as the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+'
}
```

**Example-2:**

If I need another package -that is found in Maven repo- I have to add into dependencies block as following (for instance I wanna add `fresco`):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
}
```

Then Gradle will find and install [dependency library Fresco](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.fresco/fresco/1.9.0) for me.

Usually, every Android project has already Maven repo. configurations in `build.gradle` file which is found in top of folder of the project.
For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**Example-3:**

(I have never tried this however it should be worked) 
If I have an `drawee-debug.aar` file I can add it into my project by putting it into `lib` folder as directed on Example-1 then I have to change `fileTree` line as following:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar", "*.aar"])  // "*.aar" is added
```

**Example-4:**

(alternate way of Example-3) 
If I have an `drawee-debug.aar` file also I can add it into my project by putting it into `lib` folder as directed on Example-1 then I have to change and add some lines as following:

```
dependencies {
    compile (name:'drawee-debug', ext:'aar')
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs', './libs'
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In this way, `libs` directory is defined in `allprojects` folder and `aar` file specified in `dependencies` block, like othe examples.

**Note** that after Gradle v3.0.1 `implementation` is used instead `compile` key word.

Kudos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092426/3765109

Comment: Where did you come up with `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1`?

Comment: I guess you asked because okhttp:3.4.1 is already in jar folder. If so you're right it seems wrong. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Nope! I should note that my java skills are rusty. I asked purely because I'm trying to find the right string format to compile some libs that I am including. If possible, can you update the example to use that `gson-2.2.2.jar`?

Comment: Actually I have to change and have to expand the answer. Let me change in a couple of minutes..

Comment: Thank you for quick replies on an old answer!

Comment: I guess `Example-2` explains what you asked. Isn't it?

Comment: Example 2 solves my issue. The note at the end also also saved my butt. Nice answer!

Comment: @efkan do we need to do anything else to use the functionality?

Comment: how can i import the module in my react natice components with NativeModules, how can i find the name of the library to import after adding it with implementation in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

To integrate jar file to android see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library).

In order to access the library functionality you need to create a react-native module for the functionalities which you want to access through javascript. For more info refer [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content)