# Adding a .jar in android in react-native, error Field name '??' cannot be represented in dex format

Tags: react-native, android-studio, error-handling, jar, version

I'm following adding library .jar file in android folder in react-native in
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library" with second answer.
in third step "gradlew assemble", I always encounter the error "Field name '??' cannot be represented in dex format." in Image and there's no information of it. should I install android again? What can I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab2lj.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6e0l.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0dhV.jpg)

Comment: add your source code to get answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to add *.jar* files to your React Native project , you have to configure `android/app/build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

For more options to add *.jar* file, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200627/how-to-include-jar-files-in-the-react-native-for-android#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20add%20a%20jar%20file%20to%20a,file%20of%20the%20native%2Dmodule.)
Also don't forget to specify the correct dir or create a dir *libs* under android/app and add your files there.