# Add .jar to dependencies in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am quite new to React Native but I need to create an Android Module for the Honeywell CT50 barcode scanner.

I have created a `libs` folder in MyApp/android/app as stated in these two SO posts:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892608/adding-jar-files-to-react-native/37092426#37092426)

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200627/how-to-include-jar-files-in-the-react-native-for-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The second post says I must then add the package name to the dependencies something like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+'
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
}
```

This the part I am struggling with, the formatting of the name. Here's what the contents of the .jar file looks like:

[image]

I would like to reference the `AidcManager` to do this I have tried:

```
compile "com.honeywell.aidc.AidcManager"
compile "com.honeywell.aidc:AidcManager"
compile "com.honeywell.aidc:"
```

Each time I get an error during my build saying something like:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find com.honeywell.aidc:AidcManager:.
 Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.pom
     file:/Users/XXX/.m2/repository/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.jar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.jar
     file:/XXX/node_modules/react-native/android/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.pom
     file:/XXX/node_modules/react-native/android/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.jar
     file:/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.pom
     file:/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.jar
     file:/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.pom
     file:/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager//AidcManager-.jar

Required by:
     MyApp:app:unspecified
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy .jar files in libs folder and import classes or packages from it in your .java file. There is no need to reference them in .gradle file.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How would I import the classes into the .java file? Like this import com.honeywell.aidc.AidcManager ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering wayyyyyyy to late, but might be helpful to others who are looking for this answer,

just add .jar in libs, then add below into gradle

```
implementation files('libs/<YourJarName>.jar')
```

Or

> Right click the jar and select "Add jar to project" option